# Blue screen after changing selection in 'choose connection' modal screen

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, login

When I click the gear on the top right of the login screen and change the selection, the 'choose connection' modal disappears but does not return to the login screen. Instead it is stuck on a blue screen...

The only way to get around this is to kill the app and restart. I'm using the latest version of the SDK (4.1.2)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please add following code in appdelegate class.

`[SalesforceSDKManager sharedManager].switchUserAction = ^(SFUserAccount *fromUser, SFUserAccount *toUser) {
            [weakSelf handleUserSwitch:fromUser toUser:toUser];
        };`